# Is there anyway to get the $form_state inside a hook_block_configure?

Tags: 7, forms, blocks

Is there any way to get the `$form_state` inside a `hook_block_configure()`? I'm trying to do that to make `#ajax` work on `hook_block_configure()`.

Comment: I am facing the same situation (need to implement ajax at block configure page). Why is this too localized?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have this information, but you can access to it with [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). But to access to this form (that call block_configure) you have two form_id block_admin_configure and block_add_block_form.

Comment: I made a workaround using ajax_get_form function and it worked

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to accept it and help other to figure this out.